# I can't iterate through TreeSet

Tags: java

I have to add User identified by his id into set and in runtime all users form that set have to be sorted by this id.

I've created TreeSet added some User objects and tried to iterate through it.

Here is my attempt:

```
//irrelevant code removed

    TreeSet<User> userSet = new TreeSet<User>();
    userSet.add(new User(2));
    userSet.add(new User(1));
    userSet.add(new User(3));

    Iterator<User> iterator = userSet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator.next() + " ");
    }
```

I wrote class User where is one of the fields id and constructor have id as parameter.

```
public class User {
    private int id;

    // irrelevant code removed

    public User(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // irrelevant code removed

    public String toString() {
        return id + "";
    }
}
```

When i run this code I get ClassCastException.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: OrderedUsers$User cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1188)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:531)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at OrderedUsers.<init>(OrderedUsers.java:9)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right way when you decided to use TreeSet because with TreeSet you can get ordered output. But...
Note that if you use TreeSet,  because of TreeSet is sorted you have to implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

When you implement Comparable you will get what you expected.

I suggest that you perform changes like this:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private int id;

    // irrelevant code removed

    public User(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // irrelevant code removed

    public String toString() {
        return id + "";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User u) {
        return id - u.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Or provide the `TreeSet` with a `Comparator<User>`.

Comment: +1 (added link for `Comparable`) -- also should be noted that `TreeSet` is an implementation of `SortedSet`.

Comment: However, note that in `.compareTo()`, you should ideally use `Integer.compare(id, u.id)`

Answer (score 2):

Either pass a custom `Comparator` to `TreeSet` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29) or implement `Comparable` in your model class

`TreeSet` maintains sorted order and it needs to know how `User`s can be compared

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet internally stores the object by performing comparasions with the existing ones similar to Binary Search Tree (actually its a Red-Black tree). So you need to implement interface Comparable in User or provide a custom Comparator to the TreeSet.

If you dont want the user objects to be stored in a sorted order I would recommend using ArrayList.

Method 1 :

```
 public class User implements Comparable<User>
 {
    public int compare(User u)
    {
        if( u == null)
           return 1;

        return id - u.id;
    }
 }
```

Method 2  :

```
  public class CompareUsers implements Comparator<User>
  {
        public int compareTo(User a, User b)
        {
           if(a == null)
              return -1;
           if(b == null)
               return 1;

           return  a.id - b.id;
        }

  }

   // Create an instance of this comparator class and pass to the TreeSet 
   // during initialization.

   TreeSet<User> userSet = new TreeSet<User>(new CompareUsers());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the statement at `TreeMap.java 1188`:

```
    return comparator==null ? ((Comparable<? super K>)k1).compareTo((K)k2)
        : comparator.compare((K)k1, (K)k2);
```

So if `comparator` is `null`, then it will try to cast the set member to a `(Comparable)`.  If your class doesn't implement `Comparable`, this will cause the `ClassCastException` you saw.  `comparator` is non-null only if you call the `TreeMap` constructor that provides a `Comparator` (or if you copy it from another `SortedMap` that already has a comparator).